# Vuejs: Router links not correct after passing params

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

router links are all working until I pass params to a component. The component loads correctly using the params but after that when I want to navigate to another link the route doesn't change back correctly.

For example:

I go to /error/123 and after that to /info -> what I get is /error/info

Somebody had similar issues?

```
routes: [
{
   path: '/errors',
   name: 'errors',
   component: Errors
},
{
   path: '/error/:id',
   name: 'error',
   component: Errors
},
{
   path: '/info',
   name: 'info',
   component: Info
}]
// link in another component

<v-btn :to="{ name: 'error', params: { id: id } }">Go to</v-btn>

// in error compompent

if(this.$route.params.id) {
   this.$store.dispatch("single_error", this.$route.params.id)
}

// navigation 

<v-navigation-drawer
    v-model="drawer"
    app
>
    <v-list dense v-for="(nav, i) in navs" :key="i">
        <v-list-item :to=" { path: nav.path }">
            <v-list-item-action>
                <v-icon>{{ nav.icon }}</v-icon>
            </v-list-item-action>
            <v-list-item-content>
                <v-list-item-title>{{ nav.title }}</v-list-item-title>
            </v-list-item-content>
        </v-list-item>
    </v-list>
</v-navigation-drawer>

// data for navigation

export default {
    data: () => ({
    drawer: null,
    navs: [
      { path: '/', icon: 'home', title: 'Home'},
      { path: 'errors', icon: 'error', title: 'Errors'},
      { path: 'info', icon: 'help', title: 'Info'},
    ]
    }),
}
```

Comment: Could you add to your example code to show the `/info` route itself and the link or other code you use to (re)direct to `/info`?

Comment: I added some more of my code. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL path in your `navs` element do not have the initial `/`. Try this:

```js
    navs: [
      { path: '/', icon: 'home', title: 'Home'},
      { path: '/errors', icon: 'error', title: 'Errors'},
      { path: '/info', icon: 'help', title: 'Info'},
    ]
```

---

By the way, I suggest you to use the named routes in the navigator as well.